# Wordpress issue with Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I have a theme that does not seem to be completely compatible with a plugin in wordpress.

The plugin is called: DHVC Woocommerce products.

It seems to cause the following issue:

"no such method 'reLayout' for isotope instance"

I read a bit online and it mostly seems to be due to a conflict issue (i.e. 2 versions clashing). I currently have Isotope v1.5.26). I tried to upgrade to http://isotope.metafizzy.co/isotope.pkgd.min.js however that still brought about that same issue.

Any ideas as to what next I could try?

Answer (score 1):

Your not providing enough info or any code but, in isotope v2, it is not reLayout, but layout.

```
$container.isotope('layout')
```

Comment: Actually I think that has solved the issue! Thanks.

Or well not entired, sometimes I get:
"Cannot call methods on isotope prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'layout'"

Comment: I would need to see your code or a link to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your container has isotope, if so run isotope `layout`

```
if($("#container").data('isotope')) {
    $container.isotope("layout");
}
```